# Cocos2d-JS, cpBodyFree and cpShapeFree?

Tags: chipmunk, cocos2d-js

I'm using Cocos2d-JS with Chipmunk and I want release a body and a shape. I see in the chipmunk documentation the functions cpBodyFree and cpShapeFree, but I don't know how call them in my javascript code (body.free and shape.free are not defined).

I'm already using space.removeBody and space.removeShape, but I've read that it is not enough (in fact my game gets slow on my iphone after a while because I create and delete a lot of objects).

Any help?
Thanks.

Comment: Same issue here, any update? have you found a solution?

Comment: Where you are trying to  remove the body and the shape? it's inside a collision callback? Or any event inside a step? Cause if it's that, it's not supposed to work...